# How to merge two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sample data:

```
 TableA  Table B

 ID       ID2
 ----    -----
  1        5
  2        6
  3        7
```

Expected result:

```
 ID   ID2
 ---------
  1    5
  2    6
  3    7
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Any efforts?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL SERVER Bro...

Comment: Add one more row to table B, and adjust the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Begin TRAN

CREATE TABLE #TableA(ID INT)
CREATE TABLE  #TableB (ID2 INT)

INSERT INTO #TableA
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 

INSERT INTO #TableB
SELECT 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 7 

Select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID)ROWNUM,ID INTO #Temp FROM #TableA
Select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID2)ROWNUM,ID2 INTO #Temp_Data FROM #TableB

SELECT ID,ID2 
FROM #Temp a 
INNER JOIN #Temp_Data b ON a.ROWNUM=b.ROWNUM

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: @HartHartono Welcome Bro

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server then <kbd>[CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)</kbd> may help you to get desire result as follow

```
;WITH CTE1 AS(
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS RN
     FROM Table1
 ),CTE2 AS(
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID2 ORDER BY ID2) AS RN
     FROM Table2
 )    
 SELECT * 
 FROM CTE1 
 INNER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.RN=CTE2.RN
```